# Increase the space between x.axis and x.lab in R plot

Tags: r

I would like to create a plot in R and I am using writing the following code but how can I increase the space between xlab and xaxis , also for ylab and yaxis in R?

```
    op = par(no.readonly = TRUE)
    par(mfrow=c(2, 4))
    par(mar=c(2.5,3.5, 1, .5))
    par(mgp = c(1.5, .5, 0))
    par(oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
    plot(x,y,type="l",col="red", cex=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab =1.5)
    plot(x,y,type="l",col="red", cex=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab =1.5)    
    plot(x,y,type="l",col="red", cex=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab =1.5)
    plot(x,y,type="l",col="red", cex=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab =1.5)
    plot(x,y,type="l",col="red", cex=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab =1.5)
    plot(x,y,type="l",col="red", cex=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab =1.5)
    plot(x,y,type="l",col="red", cex=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab =1.5)
    plot(x,y,type="l",col="red", cex=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab =1.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `line` argument in `title`, after calling `plot`.  For example,

```
plot(x, y, ...)
title(xlab = "x label", line = 4)
```